# Get selected checkbox values

Tags: extjs3, visualforce

I have a sencha grid with checkbox.
I need to get a selected checkbox values.
Could you please suggest me on how to do or send me a piece of code to get the values when i select a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This call will return true or false if it is checked or not, you would have to put your checkbox id in the quotes:

```
Ext.getCmp("yourCheckBoxId").checked;
```

If you want to do something the moment it gets checked you would have to add a listener in the checkbox config:

```
{
    xtype: checkbox,
    ... //other config options
    listeners: {
        check: function(checkbox, value){
           if (value) {
              alert('You checked the checkbox!');
           } else {
              alert('You unchecked the checkbox.');
           }
        }
    },
}
```

Don't forget to "accept" the answer if this works out for you (check mark at the left)